# How to set UIView size to match parent without constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect

The problem sounds easy but it is making me crazy.
I've created a white view in IB that's called iBag and by constraints it's size depends on screen size.

[image]

Now I want create a new UIView programmatically and add as subview to iBag with same size and position by this code

```
let newView = UIView()
newView.frame =  (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: iBag.frame.width, height: iBag.frame.height))
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
iBag.addSubview(newView)
```

[image]

I also tried bounds but that didn't help.
I can use constraints to solve the problem but i want to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Where are you instantiating the new view in ViewWillAppear ???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari In viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you try it in ViewDidAppear ????

Comment: Use the code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: This is because of constrains.

Comment: You should add the new view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as the frame & autolayout process won't be complete before then.  Make sure you keep a reference to your new view and only add it if this is nil as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may be called more than once

Comment: set the new view's constraints programmatically too, then it will work

Comment: @Paulw11Thank You. That's right.I should have known the issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So many answers and nobody is explaining what's wrong.

I will try.

You are setting the frame of `newView` to your superviews frame *before* the autolayout engine has started to determine your superviews position and size. So, when you use the `superviews` frame, you are using its initial frame. Which is not correct in most cases.

You have 3 ways to do it correctly:

- Use autolayout constraints for your `newView`
- Set `newView`s frame in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Which is
  called when the autolayout engine finishes determining the frames actual values. (Note: This method can be called multiple times)
- Set an autoresizing mask for `newView`

Comment: Thank you. You saved my weekend.
All tutorials tells how to format UIView and no one tells that 
update must be called on viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

**Swift 1 and 2:**

```
newView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

**Swift 3+:**

```
newView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

If it doesn't work, also this:

`iBag.autoresizesSubviews = true`

Answer (score 20):

Try this

`subview.frame = parentView.bounds`

`subview.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]`

`parentView.addSubview(subview)`

Answer (score 4):

May be this will help you

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let newView = UIView()
    newView.frame = iBag.bounds
    newView.addConstraints(iBag.constraints)
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    iBag.addSubview(newView)

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry but still no result

Comment: Are you using auto resize in storyboard or constraints layout?

Comment: After trying different things it worked but it only works in viewDidLayoutSubviews function. Anyway Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {


    newView.frame =  (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: iBag.frame.width, height: iBag.frame.height))

}
```

or you can use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` to set frame.

Because in `viewDidload` your iBag's frame is same which is in your interface builder (storyboard). Now it will change according to your constraints and device size on which you run. So, in `viewDidload` your new view get old frame not changed frame. So, it's better to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWilAppear`.

Second thing, **Either use autolayout everywhere or nowhere**. It is bad practice to use autolayout in parent view and not to child.

Comment: That is not a good solution because viewDidLayoutSubviews is called multiple times. So there will be many "newViews" created.

Comment: yeah that's right @jn-se Edited my answer! Now, it is fine i think

Answer (score 1):

may be this will work:-

```
subview.bounds.size = parentView.bounds.size

subview.center = parentView.center
```

but in your case, `width` and `height` inside the CGRect should be

```
width: parentView.bounds.size.width
height: parentView.bounds.size.height
```

and then add to it's parent as subview.

Comment: Nope , same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
let newView = UIView()
newView.frame =  (frame: CGRect(x: iBag.frame.origin.x, y: iBag.frame.origin.y, width: iBag.frame.size.width, height:  iBag.frame.size.height))
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
iBag.addSubview(newView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using constraints is likely what's wrong. If your storyboard/nib is set to use AutoLayout (which is on by default) then setting frames/bounds gets overridden by the AutoLayout system and you HAVE TO use constraints to get your layout to look right. (or set the flag that converts auto resizing masks to constraints. I don't remember what that flag is called and can't seem to find it at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up your view in viewdidload, call it in viewdidappear, so it captures the original frame of view, accordingly to the screen size

Answer (score -1):

Try use **applyConstraints**

```
parentView.addSubview(newSubview, applyConstraints: true)
```

Comment: UIView.addSubview only accepts one parameter according to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview