# Setting UICollectionView frame at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cgrectmake

I am trying to set the frame of my `UICollectionView` at runtime.

I tried using

```
mainCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width-20, height: self.view.frame.width-20)
```

in my `viewDidLoad` but unfortunately it will always stay as in `IB`.
I am not yet using `constraints`.

Otherwise resizing my cells is working in `cellForItem`:

```
 collectionCell.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width/8 * 3
```

Comment: display your correct set collectionview screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set UIView size to match parrent without constraints programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725406/how-to-set-uiview-size-to-match-parrent-without-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: The answer was already posted but deleted: it is important to set everything in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @ShadowOf this is not a duplicate of your provided link

Comment: Changing the frame size in the viewDidLoad is not safe because most of the times, view are not fully functional according to the current superview. Instead of viewDidLoad, you change the frame size inside viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear(). viewDidLayoutSubviews() is the safest place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1):

you are wrong write height because you are set width at height.

try this line without navigation bar:

```
 mainCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - (20 * 2), height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - (20 * 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in one of the LayoutSubviews overrides. This will tell collection view to update its frame.

```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        mainCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        mainCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```