# Modify the videoPreviewLayer to the SwiftUI bounds

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to improve a QR Scanner code since the current one is not respecting the .padding of the SwiftUI view neither the Spacer().
The QRScanner is a class that implements the UIViewRepresentable protocol and in the

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView
```

method I setup the view:

```
let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)//This seems to be the code that sets the size of the view.
```

However that size does not respect the SwiftUI padding and doesn't not change when rotating the iPhone.

This is the final part of the code in the makeUIView method

```
let videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer.frame = view.bounds //Suspicious code here
        videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
        return view
```

This is the parent SwiftUI view

```
VStack {
            Text("QR scanner")
                .font(.title)
            if (errorMessage != "") {
                Text(errorMessage)
            }
            if isShowingScanner {
                QRScannerView(qrCode: $qrCode, isShowingScanner: $isShowingScanner, errorMessage: $errorMessage) ////Does not respect its position!
            } else {
                if (qrCode != "") {
                    Text("QR Scanned: \(qrCode)")
                }
            }
            Spacer()//Does not respect this!
        }
        .padding()//Does not respect this either!
```

How do I change the size of the UIView as if it was a SwiftUI element?

I researched some part of the code and it seems the AVFoundation framework does not work with SwiftUI as it needs the UIViewRepresentable protocol to translate from UIKit to SwiftUI

I already tried with this question
[How to set UIView size to match parent without constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725406/how-to-set-uiview-size-to-match-parent-without-constraints-programmatically)

However it does not work as nothing is displayed after removing the UIScreen.main.bounds (also I found this code (the UIScreen.main.bounds) is deprecated) I've been unable to set the size of the UIView since it seems I do not have access in the QRScanner class to a Parent View Size property trying to use it as a @State variable to set the frame size.
I even tried setting it as a state class variable obtained from the constructor and set in SwiftUI with no luck